# Covering a horizontal "line" with 3 same sized textviews in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I was trying to create a layout which will "divide" a horizontal line by 3 and fill it with 3 text views. Even though the following is not what I want to achieve the sample is following.
[Sample design](http://i.hizliresim.com/LyYbl0.png)

So I started to write this and saw some problems.
1)I managed to write the headers next to each other but there are space between them.
2)They dont cover the whole screen
3)The colors and the background shape is different but I can correct it from my activity using ids.

So here is what I tried so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sports"
        android:text="Sports"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/science"
        android:text="Science"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sports"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/music"
        android:text="Music"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/science"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use weight property.

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sports"
        android:text="Sports"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/science"
        android:text="Science"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/music"
        android:text="Music"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sports"
        android:text="Sports"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/science"
        android:text="Science"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/music"
        android:text="Music"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I see(and upvoted it). But this pops up one more question, do I have to use several layouts for the underlying 500,400 etc? Since you changed from relative layout to linear layout I am confused on how you will do the same trick for 500,400 etc. Because they also need to cover the screen. In other words I need to cover the screen both horizontally and vertically. Can you show an example where you write the 500's on screen?

Comment: @Freshia I don't quite get what you mean by 500?

Comment: @Freshia oh, now I see. you could use GridLayout if it is dynamic, or you could just use several similar layouts as I have shown

Comment: @Freshia I have updated the code, you can see that the parent LInearLayout has vertical orientation and it can contain child Linearlayouts with horizontal orientation

Comment: It is static. You just used one linear layout. Can you write an another which includes "500 values" to show how I can combine layouts?(It is fine if you dont but I am new to xml so I don't really want to spend more time on this stuff). It can be something like this: 500 and the name above it cover the vertical line, and 500's cover the horizontal line.

Comment: This works thank you. I think I can handle the extra whitespaces myself

Comment: @Freshia no problem